# Why is the sequence of limits $\lim\limits_{V\to\infty}\lim\limits_{B\to 0}m(B,V)$ when reversed does not give the same result?

Tags: condensed-matter, mathematical-physics, phase-transition, symmetry-breaking, spin-models

For spontaneous magnetization $m$ in a sample of volume $V$, what do the limiting operations $$
\lim\limits_{V\to\infty}\lim\limits_{B\to 0}m(B,V)=0,\\
\lim\limits_{B\to 0}\lim\limits_{V\to\infty}m(B,V)\neq 0$$ physically mean and why don't they commute? $B$ denotes the applied magnetic field.

Comment: I'm guessing the magnetization is non-monotone. Monotonicity implies that limits exist and that the function is non-decreasing. $\mathrm{m(B,V)}$ is not non-decreasing

Comment: Why should they commute? -- And what do you know? I mean, do you expect an answer which introduces all concepts from magnetism from scratch?  (You don't even give any context in your question!)

Comment: @DominikCar Monotonous in *what*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The physical meaning of the two different double limits is quite obvious:
$$\lim\limits_{V\to\infty}\lim\limits_{B\to 0}m(B,V)$$ corresponds to start with a finite volume $V$, making the external magnetic field going to zero. At this point, no spontaneous magnetization is possible, due to the analytic behavior of the free energy of a finite system as a function of the thermodynamic parameter $B$, which forces $m(B,V)$ to be an odd function of $B$ ($m(-B,V)=-m(B,V)$, which implies $m(0,V)=0$).  Therefore,  magnetization density is zero for any finite $V$, and even taking the limit $V\to \infty$ will result in a zero magnetization density.

On the contrary,
$$
\lim\limits_{B\to 0}\lim\limits_{V\to\infty}m(B,V)$$ may be different from zero because, as result of the first limit, $m(B)$ for the infinite volume sample may be a non-analytic function of $B$, allowing to escape the conclusion $m=0$ at vanishing external field.

The non equivalence of the interchanged double limit is the fingerprint of a spontaneously broken symmetry: as a consequence of the thermodynamic limit, a symmetry of the hamiltonian (here the time reversal symmetry) may cease to be a symmetry of the infinite system macrostate.

Comment: Very nice and concise!

Comment: I do not understand your answer because I thought the question was about spontaneous magnetization $B$ being the *applied field*: "For spontaneous magnetization m in a sample of volume V, what do the limiting operations, etc.,...". The word spontaneous I interpret as $m \ne 0$ even if $B=0$ irrespective of the value of $V$. After all, a ferromagnetic single domain sample has nonzero *spontaneous* magnetization as long as we have a piece of crystal to speak of.

Comment: @hyportnex It is a well known fact that it is impossible to have a non zero magnetization without an external field for any finite size system. In term of space configuration the argument is very simple: in the case of $B=0$ for every configuration corresponding to a magnetization $M$, there is another configuration with magnetization $-M$ with the same probability. When averaging over all the configurations, no net magnetization can result. So, for any finite $V$, there is nothing like a "spontaneouos magnetization". It is only the thermodynamic limit which may break the argument.

Comment: I understand your argument if by $m$ you mean the statistical spatial average of all similar  samples but neither the question nor your answer mentioned averaging. Your statement "It is a well known fact that it is impossible to have a non zero magnetization without an external field for any finite size system" cannot stand without the one that follows it, never mind that a current carrying superconducting ring has a nonzero magnetic moment by itself.

Comment: @hyportnex When physicists speak about spontaneous magnetization are discussing the behavior of a macroscopic system which may undergo a magnetic phase transition below a critical temperature. Spontaneous magnetization is not used in the case of current carrying superconducting rings. Moreover, tags help to understand the context of the question (in this case it was quite clear even without looking at tags).

Comment: forget superconducting ring; "when physicists speak about" the magnetization of ferromagnetic single domain particle how do they call that?

Comment: @hyportnex A single domain is not made by one particle. It is still containing a huge number of atoms. Typical size of domains is between $10^{-4}$ and $10^{-6}$ m.

Comment: OK not particle; call it dust but ferromagnetic single domain, a microscopic sample, a piece of very small material, whatever you "physicist" would call it, how is its magnetization called? Is that spontaneous?

Comment: @hyportnex I don't see what you're getting at. The interpretation of the OP's setting by GiorgioP is the standard one, used in all statistical mechanics textbooks discussing ferromagnetism. Do you have one example of a stat. mech. book using the terminology differently?